# How do i get the implementers of a particular Widget class in VsCode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do make VsCode suggest only the implementers of a particular Widget class for example, the decoration class  [flutter decoration class docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15urQ.png)

Rather than it suggesting all available widgets for each property/widget class as shown here [VsCode ScreenCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR0CL.png)

Answer (score 0):

After typing the widget, press ctrl + space keys and wait. The values that can be received will be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Holding `ctrl` + **hovering** over the property name, or over the widget it is contained in, opens up a dialog. You can see the type of the property in that dialog.
I've attached the example image below for **AStudio**.

[image]

#### VSCode

For VSCode you `ctrl` + `click` to open the document and then `ctrl` + `click` on the property name to take you to its declaration where you can see the type.